# PHP file upload keeps throwing error

Tags: php, fopen, pem

I am uploading an rsa private key (.pem file) to my website and using fopen to read the contents but lately I keep getting the same error over and over without making much sense.

### HTML

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
```

### Upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80) {
    header('Location:https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
    die();
} 



echo $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];

//Сheck that we have a file
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
  $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "pem") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "text/plain")) {

$fh = fopen($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'], 'r');

//continue with code
  } else {
     echo "Error: Only pem files are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
?>
```

The site keeps returning the error:

> Warning: fopen(mykey.pem)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   .... on line 38

(which is fopen line). The fact it gets to the fopen state proves to me it does in fact upload but using fopen (also tried using file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']); as well unsuccessfully) returns an error.

what da puh!

### FINAL NOTES:

For whatever reason, fopen() does not like reading OpenSSL certificates and returns an eror:

> openssl_private_decrypt(): supplied
>   resource is not a valid OpenSSL
>   X.509/key resource

if you use file_get_contents it works however.

Comment: linux centos 5 - solved below. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're trying to open a wrong file(name). Since I don't see move_uploaded_file() anywhere in your code, you should probably be reading the **tmp_name** instead of **name** from the $_FILES array:

```
$fh = fopen($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
```

Comment: thanks - i'm not sure why this didn't really work (given ['name'] did return an echo but in either case it worked. Of note, you have to use file_get_contents in this area; fopen() does not function properly with pem files.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
  $fh = fopen($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
```

Comment: yep - you got it, see my final notes just as FYI